# Returning a subclass type object instead of superclass type object as demanded by interface

Tags: java, interface

I have a class called Node and another class called ClassicNode which extends Node. Now I have an interface AgentInterface implemented by ClassicNode class. The interface states that there must be a method

```
Node selection();
```

As you can see, the return type should be of type Node. But in the class ClassicNode can I implement it like this instead:-

```
ClassicNode selection(){
    //Code
}
```

Will this satisfy the interface? (since ClassicNode inherits Node)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; it's called *covariant return*. Note, though, that you cannot do the same thing with parameters; they must match exactly.

Comment: Ah, never mind.  I suppose I didn't read that carefully enough.  You are correct.

Comment: so it doesnt need exactly the same type as someone else said? any subclass object will do?

Comment: @aps: The first answer that was posted was wrong (and the author seems to have realized it, because he deleted it). Just try it out yourself and see: it will compile and run. And yes, any subclass will do - or if the return type is an interface, you can use any class that implements that interface.

Comment: Now say the return type is LinkedList<Node> as mentioned in the interface... can i still return LinkedList<ClassicNode> instead? will that satisfy the interface?

Comment: @aps: No; `GenericClass<B>` is not a subclass of `GenericClass<A>`, even if `B` is a subclass of `A`.

Comment: oh...thanks a lot...that's why it isn't compiling at one place and compiling in some other place where I have used just the subclass and not generic...

Answer (score 2):

So,why don't you do a experiment?
less work to do. 
you can just add annotation @Override upon the signature of your Method, then try to compile the code, if successfull, means that works, or failure.