# Changing the return type of an overrided method where the return type is Object in the interface - java

Tags: java, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overriding return type in extended interface - Bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864557/overriding-return-type-in-extended-interface-bad-idea)

Lets consider the following interface,

```
public interface Cat{
    public Object getCat();//returns any type of object
}

public interface DomesticCatInterface{
    public String somethinOnlyRelatedToDomesticCat();
}

public interface WildCatInterface{
    public String somethinOnlyRelatedToWildCat();
}

public class DomesticCat implements Cat, DomesticCatInterface{
    @Override
    public DomesticCat getCat(){
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String somethinOnlyRelatedToDomesticCat(){
        return "something";
    }

}

public class WildCat implements Cat, WildCatInterface{
    @Override
    public WildCat getCat(){
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String somethinOnlyRelatedToWildCat(){
        return "something";
    }
}
```

is this a good practice follow, when I need to get a reference from a class?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You already have the reference, which you're calling. What's the point?

Comment: It is valid http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475312/returning-a-subclass-type-object-instead-of-superclass-type-object-as-demanded-b?rq=1

Comment: using an interface to provide functionality relevant only to single subclass is generally a bad idea... and using common Cat interface gives you NOTHING if you return different types of objects with a method implemented from it.

Comment: @vaxquis: "using an interface to provide functionality relevant only to single subclass is generally a bad idea". Very controversial statement. Also, how do you know that there is nothing else in the Cat interface?

Comment: @Thilo as I've already said, maybe you're right. my views towards Java's OOP are heavily biased... I still use underscores in names of my Java variables *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making getCat() return an Object, make it return a Cat. This you should be able to return any Class that implements Cat. In java 5 this is called [Co-variant return types](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/covariant-return-types.html)

Comment: Yes, but he may still want to have the implementations return "WildCat" or "DomesticCat"

Comment: True, since every class is a Sub class of Object. But Cat seems cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

As every body wrote, it is possible to narrow a return type.

But to your last line question, if it is a good way to get references, the answer is no.
You won't get a *new* reference to that object, but to the calling object (that - frankly - you already have an instance to), it will just point to the same thing.

Use the `new` keyword to get new instances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (since Java 5, I believe) to narrow (*not* widen) the return type of a method when you override it.

I'd say go for it, when it helps make your code cleaner.

Note that it is still not possible to narrow (or widen) the types of method arguments.

You may also be interested in [using self-referential generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604030/how-can-an-interface-include-a-method-that-references-the-concrete-implementatio?rq=1) to force this upon the implementations of your interface.

Comment: hell, I give up on this one. maybe you're right. I don't give a damn, because what you write still doesn't make any sense to me.  as most of the things in JLS, btw... but my 5c - it *doesn't* make your code cleaner, it makes it overly verbose and littered with information classes shouldn't export. interface implementation should be as homogenous as possible. ... not to mention you made me cite Bloch, which is my nr 1 most hated Java hacker. I just hate you. ... but you still may be right. give me one link to C++ OOP page with the same view as yours, and I'll agree.